# How to implement Firebase AppCheck for Firebase Auth?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check

App Check is now showing "Authentication (Beta)" in the AppCheck panel of the firebase console. I see all my traffic logged there as "Unverified".

I can't find any documentation on how to implement App Check for auth, so how can I add AppCheck for Authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest version of the firebase sdk. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/releases

Current release is 10.13.0, since the feature is in Beta it was only added recently. I was using 10.4.0 and was seeing unverified traffic as you said, after I updated the spm package and uploaded a new build to TestFlight I started to see the first verified requests.